# Google Apps Script problem on pasting items

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

my problem is the following :

I have 2 sheets, one with IP adresses linked to hostnames on the same row. On the second sheet, there is only IP adresses and i would like to copy the hostnames from the fist sheet to the second sheet, in front of the corresponding IP adress.

This is the first sheet (Adresses IP):
[image]

And the second one (Table IP):

[image]

This is my .gs :

```
    function actualiser()
{
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let AdressesIP = ss.getSheetByName('Adresses IP'); 
  let TableIP = ss.getSheetByName('Table IP');

  let adListeHosts = AdressesIP.getRange(13,11, 10, 1).getValues();
  let adListeAd = AdressesIP.getRange(13,21, 10, 1).getValues();
  let tabListeAd = TableIP.getRange(5,6, 10, 1).getValues();

  let tableauAssociatif = {};
  let tableauRecup = {};

  for(var i in adListeAd)
  {
    tableauAssociatif[adListeAd[i]]=adListeHosts[i];
  }

  for(var j in tabListeAd)
  {
    for(var k in tableauAssociatif)
    {
      if(k == tabListeAd[j])
      {
        tableauRecup[j]=tableauAssociatif[k];
        TableIP.getRange(j+5,8).setValue(tableauRecup[j]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The problem is that it is pasting the Hostnames at the wrong place, with 9 empty cells between each Hosts :

[image]

Do you know why it doesn't paste at the right place ?

Comment: PS : I tried to write (j+10, 8) on the last row of the .gs and it makes a larger empty space between each hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using `for (var i in values)` and `values[i]` wrongly.

`for...in` is for object and `values` is in the format of Object[][]

```js
  for(let i = 0; i < adListeAd.length; i++)
  {
    tableauAssociatif[adListeAd[i][0]]=adListeHosts[i][0];
  }

  for(let j = 0; j < tabListeAd.length; j++)
  {
    for(var k in tableauAssociatif)
    {
      if(k == tabListeAd[j])
      {
        tableauRecup[j]=tableauAssociatif[k];
        TableIP.getRange(j+5,8).setValue(tableauRecup[j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

References:

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i will test it and give you a feed back